# call external API after Keycloak registration

Tags: keycloak

I  have two questions :

I need to call an external API with API keys after user registration occurs in Keycloak. How can I do it ? Can I use the registration flow and how?

I must include an external API response in the Keycloak registration API response. how can I do it?

I want to do it with authentication flows